# Concurreny update error when using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am encountering concurrent update error when using OLE DB command to execute a update procedure in SSIS.

Below is the segment of code which will check for concurrency update. Currently I removed this segment of code in order for my procedure in SSIS to execute successfully. But should I have this segment of code? Otherwise will I encounter concurrency error?

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('ConcurrentUpdated', 16, 1)
    RETURN @@ERROR
END
```

Comment: This is a custom user error message. Only you (or the developer that wrote it) can know what exactly you meant for it. We can guess what that piece of code is doing, but you'd make our jobs easier if you'd post also the code before the IF. For the moment I second @Colin 't Hart's message that it doesn't look as an SSIS problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be specifically an SSIS problem.

It seems to me that the logic of the original code is such that the if the previous update statement updates 0 rows that it indicates a concurrent update took place.

I'm guessing that the update statement includes one or more extra columns in the where clause on which previous values are matched. The update affecting 0 rows indicates that a concurrent update took place.

You'll need to show us the rest of the procedure to determine whether this is the case.